# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'TableTitle')

Tags: apex, lightning, lightning-web-components

The goal is to have a LWC that is able to build tabs for you and allow you to inline edit these tabs upon load. So I have on the screen a multi pick that pulls all of the object in the system, you select (up to 6) & then select (up to 10) the fields that you are wanting to show in your table. Then you would load the said table to allow for inline editing and data manipulation. I am trying to load a table in my LWC but I keep getting an error **Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'TableTitle')** when I try to load the table. When I go in and search the js console I am getting

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'TableTitle')
    at u (tTXLWCDattaTableController.js:4)
    at aura_prod.js:21
    at be.observe (aura_prod.js:13)
    at Mr.Er (aura_prod.js:21)
    at wo (aura_prod.js:21)
    at Mr (aura_prod.js:21)
    at aura_prod.js:21
    at Hr (aura_prod.js:21)
    at so (aura_prod.js:21)
    at Array.uo (aura_prod.js:21)
```

If I look in the user messages then it shows that I am getting data.
**{"lstDataTableColumns":[{"fieldName":"Name","label":"Name","type":"text"},{"fieldName":"Account_Short_Name__c","label":"Account Short Name","type":"Text"},{"fieldName":"Affiliate_Name__c","label":"Affiliate Name","type":"Text"}],"lstDataTableData":[{"Name":"Opportunity Tester02021-12-08 00:00:00","Id":"0010q00000iKeVsAAK"},{"Name":"Opportunity Tester12021-12-08 00:00:00","Id":"0010q00000iKeVtAAK"},{"Name":"Opportunity Tester22021-12-08 00:00:00","Id":"0010q00000iKeVuAAK"},{"Name":"Opportunity Tester32021-12-08 00:00:00","Id":"0010q00000iKeVvAAK"},{"Name":"Bruce C Campbell","Id":"0010q00000ha7rNAAQ"}],"TableTitle":"Dynamic Table - Account"}**

WHen I go to load the LWC to show the Tabs it shows the proper list **[{"Id":"a2m0q000000PGIRAA4","Name":"AIPredictionDefinition","TabViewer__c":"a0r0q000001eGTYAA2","TabViewer__r":{"Id":"a0r0q000001eGTYAA2"}},{"Id":"a2m0q000000PGIWAA4","Name":"AIPredictionEvent","TabViewer__c":"a0r0q000001eGTYAA2","TabViewer__r":{"Id":"a0r0q000001eGTYAA2"}},{"Id":"a2m0q000000PGIbAAO","Name":"AIRecordInsight","TabViewer__c":"a0r0q000001eGTYAA2","TabViewer__r":{"Id":"a0r0q000001eGTYAA2"}}]**

Component:

```
<aura:component controller="QueryBuilderLightning"
            implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" 
            access="global">
<aura:attribute name="moretabs" type="Aura.Component[]"/>

<!-- Modal attribute, default not showing/closed-->
<aura:attribute name="isModelBoxOpen" type="boolean" default="false"/>

<!-- Attributes for the record info.  tvID is the record ID-->
<aura:attribute name="tabInfo" type="TabViewer__c" default="{'sobjectType':'TabViewer__c','Name':'New Tab'}"/>
<aura:attribute name="tvID" type="string"/>

<!--Attributes for Object selection dual picklist
            Objectoptions - Initial list filled out by controller
            and fills the list with returned objects
            selectedObjects - Objects chosen by the user from the
            picklist, dynamically handled with a handler
            min/max - Allowed number of items to be chosen from the
            picklist
-->
<aura:attribute name="objectOptions" type="List" />
<aura:attribute name="selectedObjects" type="List"
                default = "['Accounts', 'Marketing', 'Contacts']" />
<aura:attribute name="min" type="Integer" default="1" />
<aura:attribute name="max" type="Integer" default="6" />
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />                
    <lightning:tabset variant="scoped" aura:id="objectSet">
        <lightning:tab label="Admin">
            <div class="slds-card">
                <div class="slds-grid">
                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2" aura:id="newTabViewDiv">
                        <lightning:dualListbox aura:id="chooseObjects"
                                                name="objectPicker"
                                                label="Select 1-6 Objects"
                                                sourceLabel="Available Objects"
                                                selectedLabel="Selected Objects"
                                                options="{!v.objectOptions}"
                                                value="{!v.selectedObjects}"
                                                min="{!v.min}"
                                                max="{!v.max}"
                                                onchange="{!c.handleObjectChange}"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- <div>
                <lightning:button label="Add tabs" onclick="{!c.addTab}"/>
            </div> -->
            <!--Use "slds-m-around_xx-large" class to add standard X-Large padding to the component--> 
            <div class="slds-var-m-around_xx-large">        
                <lightning:button variant="brand" 
                label="Save TabView" 
                title="Save TabView" 
                onclick="{! c.openModel }" />
                <!--Use aura:if tag to display Model Box, on the bese of conditions. [isModelBoxOpenboolean attribute] -->   
                <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isModelBoxOpen}">            
                    <!--###### MODAL BOX Start######--> 
                    <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
                        <div class="slds-modal__container">
                            <!-- ###### MODAL BOX HEADER Start ######-->
                            <header class="slds-modal__header">
                                <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:close"
                                onclick="{! c.closeModel }"
                                alternativeText="close"
                                variant="bare-inverse"
                                class="slds-modal__close"/>
                                <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">Create New TabView</h2>
                            </header>
                            <!--###### MODAL BOX BODY Part Start######-->
                            <div class="slds-modal__content slds-var-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <lightning:input name="tvName" label="Enter a name for new TabViewer" placeholder="TabViewer Name..."/>
                                </div>
                            
                            </div>
                            <!--###### MODAL BOX FOOTER Part Start ######-->
                            <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                                <lightning:button variant="neutral" 
                                label="Cancel"
                                title="Cancel"
                                onclick="{! c.closeModel }"/>
                                <lightning:button variant="brand" 
                                label="Ok"
                                title="Ok"
                                onclick="{! c.addTab}"/>
                            </footer>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                    <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
                    <!--###### MODAL BOX Part END Here ######-->            
                </aura:if>
            </div>
        </lightning:tab>
        {!v.moretabs}
    </lightning:tabset>
    
</aura:component>
```

js Controller:

```
({
init: function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.getObjectName");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {           
            var allValues = response.getReturnValue();
            var plValues = [];
            for (var i=0; i < allValues.length; i++) {
                plValues.push({
                    label: allValues[i],
                    value: allValues[i]
                });
            }
            component.set("v.objectOptions", plValues);
        }                    
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
 },
addTab: function(component, event) {
    console.log('Click - ' + component.get("!v.value"));
    helper.saveTab(component);
    // Function setup
    component.set("v.isModelBoxOpen", false);
    // Save TabView top level Record
    // Dev Note: Re-Factor to set up multiple helper functions
    var body = component.get("v.moretabs");
    var objectTabs = component.get("v.selectedObjects")
    var newlst = [];
    newlst.push(body);
    for(var i = 0; i < objectTabs.length; i++){
        $A.createComponent("lightning:tab", {
            "label": objectTabs[i],
            "id": objectTabs[i],
            "onactive": component.getReference("c.addContent")
        }, function (newTab, status, error) {
            if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                newlst.push(newTab);
                
                component.set("v.moretabs", newlst);
            } else {
                throw new Error(error);
            }
        });
    }
    console.log('More Tabs length: ' + component.get("v.moretabs").length)
},
addContent : function(component, event) {
    var tab = event.getSource();
    var cmp = component.getSource();
    var tabLabel = tab.get("v.id");
    // dbID = event.get("v.testAttr");
    // console.log('Test Attr: ' + dbID);
    $A.createComponent("c:qrlwcvanilla", {
        "label": tabLabel,
        }, function (newContent, status, error) {
        if (status === "SUCCESS") {
            tab.set('v.body', newContent);
        } else {
            throw new Error(error);
        }
    });
   
},
handleObjectChange: function (component, event, helper) {
    var selectedValues = event.getParam("value");
    component.set("v.selectedObjects", selectedValues);
},
openModel: function(component, event, helper) {
    // for Display Model,set the "isModelBoxOpen" attribute to "true"
    component.set("v.isModelBoxOpen", true);
},
closeModel: function(component, event, helper) {
    // for Hide/Close Model,set the "isModelBoxOpen" attribute to "False"  
    component.set("v.isModelBoxOpen", false);
},
})
```

JS Helper:

```
({
saveTab  : function(component, event) {
    var recordName = component.find("tvName").get('v.value');
    console.log('tvName: '+ tvName);

    var tabViewSave =  component.get("c.saveTabView");
    tabViewSave.setParams({
    "tv": recordName
   });
    tabViewSave.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        console.log('Save Status: ' + state);            
        if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
            component.set("v.tvID", response.getReturnValue());
        } else if (state === "ERROR") {
            var errors = response.getError();
            if (errors) {
                if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                    console.log("Error message:  " + 
                    errors[0].message);
                }
            } else {
                console.log("Unknown error");
            }
        }
    });
$A.enqueueAction(tabViewSave);       
}
})
```

LWC HTML Template:

```
<template>
<lightning-card>
    <div class="slds-p-horizontal_small"></div>
    <lightning-layout multiple-rows="true" vertical-align="end">
        <lightning-layout-item size="12" padding="around-small">
            <div if:true={DataTableResponseWrappper}>
                <h1> I AM HERE</h1>
                <div class="slds-text-heading_small">DataTableResponseWrappper.Name</div>
                <lightning-datatable data={finalSObjectDataList} 
                                    columns={DataTableResponseWrappper.lstDataTableColumns} 
                                    key-field="Id"
                                    hide-checkbox-column="true"
                                    ></lightning-datatable>
            </div>
        </lightning-layout-item>
    </lightning-layout>
</lightning-card>
</template>
```

LWC JS

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import getDynamicTableDataList from '@salesforce/apex/DynamicLWCDataTableController.GetWrapperOfSObjectFieldColumnActionValues';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';

export default class Dynamic_LWC_Data_Table extends LightningElement {
@track DataTableResponseWrappper;
@track finalSObjectDataList;
@api objRecId;

//_wiredResult;


@wire(getDynamicTableDataList, {TableName: '$objRecId'})
wiredContacts({ error, data }) 
{
    try {
        //console.log('%c%s', 'color: #2703f3', 'lwc objRecId: ', this.objRecId);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Error with console log: ' + e);
    }

    if(data) 
    {
        //this._wiredResult = data;
        //this.refreshData
    console.log('lwc data option invoked');
    console.log('%c%s', 'color: #e50000', JSON.stringify(data));
    
       let sObjectRelatedFieldListValues = [];
        
       for (let row of data.lstDataTableData) 
       {
            const finalSobjectRow = {}
            let rowIndexes = Object.keys(row); 
            rowIndexes.forEach((rowIndex) => 
            {
                const relatedFieldValue = row[rowIndex];
                if(relatedFieldValue.constructor === Object)
                {
                    this._flattenTransformation(relatedFieldValue, finalSobjectRow, rowIndex)        
                }
                else
                {
                    finalSobjectRow[rowIndex] = relatedFieldValue;
                }
                
            });
            sObjectRelatedFieldListValues.push(finalSobjectRow);
        }
        this.DataTableResponseWrappper = data;
        this.finalSObjectDataList = sObjectRelatedFieldListValues;
    } 
    else if (error) 
    {
        //this._wiredResult = error;
        alert('Please to reload ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        this.error = error;
    }
}

// refreshData() {
//     return refreshApex(this._wiredResult);
// }

_flattenTransformation = (fieldValue, finalSobjectRow, fieldName) => 
{        
    let rowIndexes = Object.keys(fieldValue);
    rowIndexes.forEach((key) => 
    {
        let finalKey = fieldName + '.'+ key;
        finalSobjectRow[finalKey] = fieldValue[key];
    })
}
}
```

Been working on this for 2 weeks and just dont understand what is going wrong.. Is there something that someone can recommend?

Comment: You do have a typo in your markup. `<div class="slds-text-heading_small">{DataTableResponseWrapper.TableTitle}</div>` should actually be `<div class="slds-text-heading_small">{DataTableResponseWrappper.TableTitle}</div>`. Notice `one extra p in wrapper`.

Comment: @SachinHooda When I update to the new template above I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you please update the question with latest code?

Comment: I had updated it prior to posting the response.

Comment: Your code does seem to acces `TableTitle` anywhere.. are you sure you still getting the same error?